# How can i solve this php artisan issue? Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Tags: laravel, composer-php

[This is  ***Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\Commands\TestCommand] does not exist.*** error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bLHX.png)

Comment: Please share more details

Comment: I have the same error when i use the php artisan command or composer dump-autoload

Comment: Good to know - but if you want help, you need to share more details. You can start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and adding more details to your question by editing

Comment: Are you click on this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bLHX.png

Comment: No, thank you. Please add all information in text form to your question. That's way more accessible than any screenshot

Answer (score 0):

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException : Target
> class [] does not exist.

message, this could be helpful:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

also, this could be helpful

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: When I use composer dump-autoload I have the same error 
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [NunoMaduro\Collision\Adapters\Laravel\Commands\TestCommand] does not exist.

Comment: Or php artisan config:cache

Comment: @SoudeJacques Can you try installing PHPUnit 8.4 and see if the problem is resolved then?